# Ошибка выполнения ExecutorService

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Использую ExecutorService выводит ошибку

```
    java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@19fc62cb rejected from 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@2a921aa8[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

в цикле запускаю

```
 final ExecutorService exService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

            for (String fileName : files) {

                createFile(filename);
            }
            exService.shutdown();

     public void createFile(String name){

            exService.submit(new Thread() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                 ..........
                   }
                }
```

В чем может быть дело

Comment: может быть в том, что вы выключаете ExecutorService (exService.shutdown()) сразу же, как только поставили в очередь свои задачи?

Comment: и вообще непонятно, зачем создавать новые потоки, если нужно в exService.submit() передавать Runnable

Comment: чтобы они выполнялись в отдельном потоке по очередно а не сразу

Comment: не вижу связи того, что вы хотите жостич с тем, что делаете.

Comment: а разве не имеет здесь значения что я передаю ведь он все равно наследуется от Runnable